# Connecting Rails 3.2 to existing Oracle Database

Tags: ruby, oracle, oracle11g, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I currently have my Rails 3.2 environment connected with an already existing database, with the oracle_enhanced-adapter handling the connection. What I need to do now is take the already existing tables (which probably aren't in ActiveRecord format) and generate models, controllers, and views for them. However, I'm not sure how to go about creating these. Do I need to do it manually?

As an example, here's the device table in my database:

```
Device_Name, VARCHAR2(32 BYTE), primary key
Device_Desc, VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)
Created_By, VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
Creation_Date, DATE
Last_Updated_By, VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
Last_Updated_Date, DATE
```

How would I get a controller, model, and view for this in rails. Do I need to manually create the model? Or is this all I would need:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name="Device"
  self.primary_key="Device_Name"
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that should work.  Did you try it?

Comment: You will have to create the controllers , views, models for this. There are no generators available which can generate all these based on the database table you created.